# rails server error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hey guys
I got this error from rails server, anyone can tell what's the problem? Thanks

```
 root@makserver:/usr/local/apps/homeland# rails s
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bundler/gems/authlogic-6e2745b/lib/authlogic/crypto_providers/aes256.rb:1:in `require': no such file to load -- openssl (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bundler/gems/authlogic-6e2745b/lib/authlogic/crypto_providers/aes256.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bundler/gems/authlogic-6e2745b/lib/authlogic.rb:59:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bundler/gems/authlogic-6e2745b/lib/authlogic.rb:59:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bundler/gems/authlogic-6e2745b/lib/authlogic.rb:6:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bundler/gems/authlogic-6e2745b/lib/authlogic.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `require'
    from /usr/local/apps/homeland/config/application.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install openssl dependency

On ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install libopenssl-ruby
```

Answer (score 0):

It cannot find the openssl native library. If you're in ubuntu or any other aptitude enabled linux distro try running `apt-get install openssl`. If you're on mac, install XCode.

Comment: I have same problem, but openssl was already installed. This is probably something else.